# How to get rid of second press enter with gets in C?

Tags: c, fgets

I've got a simple bit of code and I come across with a following problem - when I invoke function playerGuess() second time it doesn't allow me to input anything. It looks like program presses enter automatically. Why is that? Can you please help?

```
 int main(void)
 {


 void playerGuess();
 void playerGuess();
 }

 void playerGuess()
{
  char playerInput[2];
  int num, row, colum;
  printf("Enter a grid reference (a1 - j0): ");
  fgets(playerInput, 3, stdin);
  printf("%s", playerinput);
}
```

Comment: `char playerInput[10]; fgets(playerInput, sizeof playerInput, stdin);`  Increase buffer size to a reasonable value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`playerInput` is too short.  You need room for your input, plus a newline, plus nul.  Your first `fgets()` stops before the end of the line because it's out of buffer space (though you overrun the buffer anyway, because you specify a size larger than the actual array)... then the second `fgets()` reads the rest of the line (which has the newline).

Answer (score 1):

If the result from fgets does not end with a newline you have not read all the data.
you now need to decide what to do with the unread data. one option would be to call getchar until you see a newline (or EOF)

```
// discard he rest of the line:

if(! strchr( playerinput,'\n')
{
  int c;
  do 
  {
    c=getchar(stdin);
  }
  while ( c != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```